# Day of the week and time on where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I have the following SQL query that works fine. Depending on the row's timezone, it gets the row within a timeframe

```
SELECT *, (now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time AS local_time 
FROM contact INNER JOIN account ON account.id = contact.account_id 
WHERE (now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time BETWEEN '17:30'::time AND '22:00'::time
```

But I would like to have different times if it's the weekend or the weekday. On the weekend, I want 15:30 instead of 17:30

How would this be done with Postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`EXTRACT(DOW FROM ...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get the day of the week. Then use a [`CASE ... END`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) retuning 15:30 when it is a Saturday or a Sunday and 17:30 otherwise.

```
SELECT *,
       (now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time AS local_time 
       FROM contact
            INNER JOIN account
                       ON account.id = contact.account_id 
       WHERE (now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone)::time BETWEEN CASE
                                                                   WHEN EXTRACT(DOW FROM now() AT TIME ZONE account.timezone) IN (6, 0)
                                                                     THEN '15:30'::time
                                                                   ELSE
                                                                     '17:30'::time
                                                                 END
                                                                 AND '22:00'::time;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with simple boolean logic:

```
SELECT *, (now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone)::time AS local_time 
FROM contact c INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON a.id = c.account_id 
WHERE (EXTRACT(DOW FROM now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone) IN (6, 0) AND
       (now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone)::time BETWEEN '15:30'::time AND '22:00'::time
      ) OR
      (EXTRACT(DOW FROM now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone) NOT IN (6, 0) AND
       (now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone)::time BETWEEN '17:30'::time AND '22:00'::time
      );
```

Because of the repetition, I might be inclined to phrase this as:

```
SELECT *, nowtz::time AS local_time 
FROM (VALUES (now() AT TIME ZONE a.timezone)) v(nowtz) CROSS JOIN
     contact c INNER JOIN
     account a
     ON a.id = c.account_id 
WHERE (EXTRACT(DOW FROM nowtz) IN (6, 0) AND
       (nowtz::time BETWEEN '15:30'::time AND '22:00'::time)
      ) OR
      (EXTRACT(DOW FROM nowtz) NOT IN (6, 0) AND
       (nowtz::time BETWEEN '17:30'::time AND '22:00'::time)
      )
```

The `WHERE` logic can be simplified to:

```
WHERE (EXTRACT(DOW FROM nowtz) IN (6, 0) AND nowtz::time >= '15:30'::time OR
       nowtz::time >= '17:30'::time 
      ) AND
      nowtz::time <= '22:00'::time
```